# XSLT template - Backslash return issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I am calling a template to populate a variable. The template is being passed a complete UNC path, and is to return just the folder path portion. But it is changing the backslashes to forward slashes.

Here is the template:

```
<xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
<xsl:param name="string"/>
<xsl:param name="char"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($string, $char)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $char)"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $char)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise/>
</xsl:choose>
```

and here is how it is called:

```
  <xsl:variable name="folderpath">
<xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
  <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$filepath"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'\'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

$filepath is populated with: \vboxsvr\SharedFolder_Assets\90min.mov

I am currently being returned: //vboxsvr/SharedFolder/_Assets/ when i want: \vboxsvr\SharedFolder_Assets\

Any advise would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are outputting a forward slash in the template, which could explain it...

```
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
```

You really need to output the `$char` variable

```
<xsl:value-of select="$char" />
```

Try this template

```
<xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="char"/>
  <xsl:if test="contains($string, $char)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $char)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$char" />
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $char)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a test and it does work like it should! So the problem must be something else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="char"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string, $char)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $char)"/>
      <xsl:text>\</xsl:text>    <!-- EDITED -->
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $char)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise/>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A">
  <xsl:variable name="filepath" select="text()" />
  <xsl:variable name="folderpath">
  <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$filepath"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'\'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:element name="B">
    <xsl:value-of select="$folderpath" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with the test XML file

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<A>\vboxsvr\SharedFolder_Assets\90min.mov</A>
```

gives the following (correct) output:

```
xsltproc a.xslt a.xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <B>\vboxsvr\SharedFolder_Assets\</B>
```

EDITED: changed '/' to '\'  which yields the desired outcome